# Creating water with p5.js

Tags: javascript, html, game-physics, p5.js

I'm trying to create some water effects in p5.js with waves and everything, but I can't seem to get the waves in the water to work. I am creating the waves off of [this](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/make-a-splash-with-dynamic-2d-water-effects--gamedev-236) article by Michael Hoffman. I created two classes for the water, one class called "Springs," which simulates the spring effect of the water, and one class called "Liquid", which just hold a list of springs and some constants.

To display the water, I used p5's beginShape() and vertex() functions to create the surface of the water. I went through and created a vertex of the height of each spring.

The water right now is staying static. I want the water to create a wave only when a ball hits the surface of the water. I have set the Liquid's "contains" method to true to just to see if the waves are working.

I want to know if there is a problem with the way I am drawing the water. Previously, there would be a spring-like effect when I clicked, except the entire surface of the water would remain a rectangle. Is there something wrong with using vectors to create waves in the water? It seemed like a simpler solution to creating the waves than drawing trapezoids like Hoffman suggests, but it turns out I can draw trapezoids easily with p5.js.

Thanks for the help.

Here is the code:

```
var balls = [];

var liquid; 

function Liquid(s) {
    this.springs = s;
    this.tension = 0.025;
    this.dampening = 0.025;
    this.spread = 0.25;
}

function Spring() {
    this.targetHeight = 0;
    this.height = 0;
    this.vel = 0;

    this.update = function(dampening, tension) {
        let x = this.targetHeight - this.height;
        this.vel += (tension * x - this.vel * dampening);
        this.height += this.vel;
    }
}

Liquid.prototype.update = function () {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.springs.length; i++)
        this.springs[i].update(this.dampening, this.tension);

    var lDeltas = [];
    var rDeltas = [];

    // do some passes where columns pull on their neighbours
    for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.springs.length; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                lDeltas[i] = this.spread * (this.springs[i].height - this.springs[i - 1].height);
                this.springs[i - 1].vel += lDeltas[i];
            }
            if (i < this.springs.length - 1)
            {
                rDeltas[i] = this.spread * (this.springs[i].height - this.springs[i + 1].height);
                this.springs[i + 1].vel += rDeltas[i];
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < this.springs.length; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
                this.springs[i - 1].height += lDeltas[i];
            if (i < this.springs.length - 1)
                this.springs[i + 1].height += rDeltas[i];
        }
    }
}

Liquid.prototype.splash = function (index, speed) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < this.springs.length)
        this.springs[i].vel = speed;
}

Liquid.prototype.display = function () {
    fill(0, 0, 255);
    beginShape();
    vertex(0, height - this.springs[0].height);
    for (var i = 0; i < this.springs.length; i++) {
        vertex(i * (width / this.springs.length), height-this.springs[i].height); //consider using the map function
    }
    vertex(width, height);
    vertex(0, height);
    endShape(CLOSE);
}

Liquid.prototype.contains = function(m) {
    return true;
};

function Mover(m, x, y) {
    this.mass = m;
    this.position = createVector(x,y);
    this.velocity = createVector(0,0);
    this.acceleration = createVector(0,0);
}

// f = m / a --> a = f / m

Mover.prototype.applyForce = function(force) {
    var f = p5.Vector.div(force,this.mass);
    this.acceleration.add(f);
}

Mover.prototype.update = function() {
    this.velocity.add(this.acceleration);
    this.position.add(this.velocity);
    this.acceleration.mult(0); //acceleration must be cleared; does not add to itself!
};

Mover.prototype.display = function() {
    stroke(0); //black outline
    strokeWeight(2); //make it more visible
    fill(255,127); //give it a gray color
    ellipse(this.position.x,this.position.y,this.mass*16,this.mass*16); //create an ellipse at the position
};

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    background(255);
    var temp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 340; i++) { //340 is an arbitrary num
        var tempSpring = new this.Spring();
        tempSpring.targetHeight = height/2;
        tempSpring.height = height/2;
        temp[i] = tempSpring;
    }
    liquid = new Liquid(temp);
    liquid.display();
}

function draw() {
    background(255);
    for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {

        if(liquid.contains(balls[i])) {
            liquid.splash(balls[i].x, 0.05);
        }
        liquid.update();
        liquid.display();
        // Gravity is scaled by mass here!
        var gravity = createVector(0, 0.1*balls[i].mass);
        // Apply gravity
        balls[i].applyForce(gravity);
        balls[i].update();
        balls[i].display();


    }
    liquid.display();
}

function mousePressed() {
    balls[balls.length] = new Mover(5, mouseX, mouseY);
}
```

Comment: Start reducing your code. Simple remove all the interaction parts (ball, clicks, etc) and start your sketch in a state that triggers a spring on frame 1. Then start checking the code you have left to see if data actually changes from frame to frame, by tracing the function calls you've set up. Do lDeltas and rDeltas change? If not, start looking at the variables that _should_ cause them to change: are they changing? If not, look at what's supposed to change _those_, are _they_ changing? If not, etc.

Comment: I agree with MIke. You need to [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and then post a [mcve] showing a specific step. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

where to start:

- there's no such thing as `balls[i].x`.
- undefined variable 'i' in splash().
- you're using the ball's x coordinate to index into the springs array (inside splash()), this doesn't seem right. firstly the x-coordinate ranges from 0 to width, and the springs array indices range from 0 to 339. secondly, the x coordinate is a non-integer value, so using it to index an array won't work.
- the balls always splash the water
- the water doesn't act on the balls

the single best way to find this stuff is to learn how to use the debugger in your browser, step through the code line by line, inspect all the things and make sure they match up with what you expect. most of these simple errors will jump out at you immediately.

```js
var balls = [];

var liquid;

function Liquid(s) {
  this.springs = s;
  this.tension = 0.025;
  this.dampening = 0.025;
  this.spread = 0.25;
}

function Spring() {
  this.targetHeight = 0;
  this.height = 0;
  this.vel = 0;

  this.update = function(dampening, tension) {
    let x = this.targetHeight - this.height;
    this.vel += tension * x - this.vel * dampening;
    this.height += this.vel;
  };
}

Liquid.prototype.update = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.springs.length; i++)
    this.springs[i].update(this.dampening, this.tension);

  var lDeltas = [];
  var rDeltas = [];

  // do some passes where columns pull on their neighbours
  for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.springs.length; i++) {
      if (i > 0) {
        lDeltas[i] =
          this.spread * (this.springs[i].height - this.springs[i - 1].height);
        this.springs[i - 1].vel += lDeltas[i];
      }
      if (i < this.springs.length - 1) {
        rDeltas[i] =
          this.spread * (this.springs[i].height - this.springs[i + 1].height);
        this.springs[i + 1].vel += rDeltas[i];
      }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < this.springs.length; i++) {
      if (i > 0) this.springs[i - 1].height += lDeltas[i];
      if (i < this.springs.length - 1) this.springs[i + 1].height += rDeltas[i];
    }
  }
};

Liquid.prototype.splash = function(index, speed) {
  if (index >= 0 && index < this.springs.length) this.springs[floor(index)].vel = speed;
};

Liquid.prototype.display = function() {
  fill(0, 0, 255);
  beginShape();
  vertex(0, height - this.springs[0].height);
  for (var i = 0; i < this.springs.length; i++) {
    vertex(i * (width / this.springs.length), height - this.springs[i].height); //consider using the map function
  }
  vertex(width, height);
  vertex(0, height);
  endShape(CLOSE);
};

Liquid.prototype.contains = function(m) {
  return true;
};

function Mover(m, x, y) {
  this.mass = m;
  this.position = createVector(x, y);
  this.velocity = createVector(0, 0);
  this.acceleration = createVector(0, 0);
}

// f = m / a --> a = f / m

Mover.prototype.applyForce = function(force) {
  var f = p5.Vector.div(force, this.mass);
  this.acceleration.add(f);
};

Mover.prototype.update = function() {
  this.velocity.add(this.acceleration);
  this.position.add(this.velocity);
  this.acceleration.mult(0); //acceleration must be cleared; does not add to itself!
};

Mover.prototype.display = function() {
  stroke(0); //black outline
  strokeWeight(2); //make it more visible
  fill(255, 127); //give it a gray color
  ellipse(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.mass * 16, this.mass * 16); //create an ellipse at the position
};

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(255);
  var temp = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 340; i++) {
    //340 is an arbitrary num
    var tempSpring = new Spring();
    tempSpring.targetHeight = height / 2;
    tempSpring.height = height / 2;
    temp[i] = tempSpring;
  }
  liquid = new Liquid(temp);
  liquid.display();
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  liquid.update();
  liquid.display();

  for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    var ball = balls[i];

    if (liquid.contains(ball)) {
      liquid.splash(ball.position.x, 54.5);
    }
    //liquid.display();
    // Gravity is scaled by mass here!
    var gravity = createVector(0, 0.1 * ball.mass);
    // Apply gravity
    ball.applyForce(gravity);
    ball.update();
    ball.display();
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  balls[balls.length] = new Mover(5, mouseX, mouseY);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background: black;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
```